# How to generate a column with a series of numbers based on a min and max value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table structured as so:

```
fake_id          start          end          misc_data
------------------------------------------------------
1                101            105          ab
1                101            105          cd
1                101            105          ef
2                117            123          gh
2                117            123          ij
2                117            123          kl
2                117            123          mn
3                51             53           op
3                51             53           qr
```

Notice that the fake_id field is not really a primary key, but is repeated a number of times equal to the number of distinct odd numbers in the range specified by start and end. The *real* id for each record is one of the odd numbers in that range. I need to write a query that returns fake_id, misc_data, and another column that contains those odd numbers to produce a real id, as follows:

```
fake_id          real_id          misc_data
------------------------------------------
1                101              ab
1                103              cd
1                105              ef
2                117              gh
2                119              ij
2                121              kl
2                123              mn
3                51               op
3                53               qr
```

As far as I know, there is no guarantee that there will be no gaps in the sequence (for example, there might be no records for range 21-31). How do I tell the query (or procedure, but query is preferable) that for each record with a particular fake_id, it should return the next odd number between start and end?

Also, is there a way to make the values for misc_data belong to a particular real_id? Using the second table as an example, how could I tell the query that "ab" belongs to real_id 101 instead of 103?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you plan to order the new values for real_id?

Answer (score 4):

Guessing here that you plan to sort on `misc_data`:

```
SELECT "fake_id",
       ((ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY "start"
                        ORDER BY "misc_data")-1)*2)+"start" AS "real_id",
       "misc_data"
FROM t
ORDER BY "misc_data";
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae23c/23

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not answering sooner or to the individual comments. @John Dewey, I believe when I tried your script it did not correctly keep the gaps between the start-end series, but I was motivated to learn more about the `PARTITION` keyword and I think I am more enlightened now.

Since this was for an ETL task, I ended up writing code to generate the real IDs in a loop on the extract (I guess it would also count as a transform) side.